# Zustand is not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zustand

I am trying to simply update the token with the help of a setter function in zustand, but it is not working.

here is my code:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'

interface AuthTokenProps {
  authToken: string
  setAuthToken: (data: string) => void
}

const useAuthToken = create<AuthTokenProps>(set => ({
  authToken: '',
  setAuthToken: data => {

    set((state) => ({ authToken: data }))
  },
}))

export default useAuthToken
```

here are my imports and usage:

```
const { authToken: token, setAuthToken } = useAuthToken.getState()
...
<button 
className="py-2 px-3 bg-cyan-600"
onClick={() => setAuthToken('new updated value')}> 
   update token 
 </button>
```

NOTE: I can verify that the `setAuthToken` function is getting called and the correct value is getting passed through it, it's just not updating the state. any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: use this syntax `const increasePopulation = useBearStore((state) => state.increasePopulation)` just like the [docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#then-bind-your-components-and-thats-it)

Comment: as I said, I can already call the 'setAuthToken' function, if I put a console.log there it prints, but inside that function, set() is not updating my value, that's my issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-swirles-ktfdel?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React components here, you shouldn't use getState, you should use the hook instead.

`const {authToken: token, setAuthToken} = useAuthToken();`
Then the component re-renders when the value of authToken updates.
When using getState, there's no way for component to react to the changes of the value `token`.
if you're using the value somewhere in an API function or something.
It should be like

```
const token = useAuthToken.getState().authToken
const result = await .....
```

Or in case you're using vanilla.js and have your own re-render functionality, you can subscribe to the state updates (to trigger render manually).

`const unsubscribe = useAuthToken.subscribe(forceUpdateHTMLElement)` and `forceUpdateHTMLElement` could be a callback function meant to trigger a re-render in the UI.